# Simple method for accepting command-line input for a standard Windows service written in C#?

Tags: c#, console, service, design-patterns, interpreter

I have written a pretty simple Windows service in C# that starts up automatically and runs A-okay. I was wondering the best method to have the service accept command-line input -- it will always be from the same user (admin), and the service itself is fully trusted (LocalSystem).

I know a little (very little) about design pattern terminology -- should I be looking to wrap this simple service in an Interpreter-style pattern? Is this too complex, and is there a way to do it through the program's entry point? (As if I was just doing a simple Console app that could take string[] args?)

Basically it should accept some very specific grammar (specific commands) which can be issued via console whenever, and only those specific commands (to hopefully avoid any of a variety of security issues).

If this needs clarification, let me know, and thanks for any suggestions (or even solutions)!

Comment: Usually the whole POINT of a service is it doesn't need or want command-line input.  Perhaps if you were a little more clear about what you're trying to do we can help better.

Comment: when it is called from the command line, does it need to interact with the same instance that is running as a service? Or can it be a completely separate and independent instance?

Comment: Berry-- The service itself is a basic watchdog, and only serves to keep a few programs running. If they terminate for any reason, it restarts them. It does this in a multithreaded way. Since it is already pretty powerful (in terms of permissions), I really just need to communicate with it in some meaningful way locally while it runs, doing its thing. Thoughts? And thanks.

Comment: Matt Wrock-- Interacting with its own instance (what I eventually want to be a singleton anyway) would be best, but not strictly necessary. Since it is already multithreaded and not breaking, I figure some method of getting it input (again, hopefully from console) would be simplest (others will use this service, too). I guess I imagine it noticing console input, accepting it if it is within its predefined grammar range, and making a thread that will do simple, specific system tasks on the server. Thoughts? And thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by having a console application modify my configuration file which my service knew to check for by monitoring the folder for changes.

Comment: Great idea, but I imagine this would need lots of logic on the service-side to sanity check the parameters in the configuration file. Could be totally wrong. I still might have to go this route, though.

Comment: Well, I would put the logic in both places - the console app so that it does not mess up the format, and the consuming service, so that it does not blow up while executing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can add App.Config file in your project, Windows Service can access app.config on same folder as yourapp.exe.config.

Configuration in .net is highly organized in terms of grammar and customization benefits.

Using App.config will not require you to change your installation settings as well.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have described, this is what you are looking for:

[Create and communicate with an Unattended Windows Service using .NET](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/WinService.aspx)

> The OnCustomCommand event allows an
>   application to interact with a running
>   service by passing in integer values.

...

> Once the service has started you send
>   integer commands to it using the
>   ServiceController's ExecuteCommand
>   method.

Comment: Really useful, but integer acceptance only will probably not work so well in this case.